# Looking for delta table indexes as my primary key

Tags: performance, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I am brand new for databricks, and Detla tables are presented to me having 4 main features (QRPG)

1. Quality
2. Reliable by having ACID transactions
3. Performance by having index
4. Governance by using Table ACL, and unity catalog

I want to be able to use this generated indexes at least as my primary key, but by far I could not find anything to see or have access to this indexes that are improving performance.

Please kindly help

Answer (score 0):

It's really depends on what you mean under "able to use this generated indexes". There are few features on Delta that fit under an umbrella of "indexing":

- [Data skipping](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#data-skipping) - ability to store min/max statistics in the Delta table transaction log, so when you're reading the data, Delta will skip files that doesn't contain a specific value.  In combination with [OPTIMIZE ... ZORDER BY](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#z-ordering-multi-dimensional-clustering) it allows better skipping of the data as related data is stored closed together.  Data skipping works best with numeric & date/time columns, and short strings. But it may not work well when you search for values that fit into the range of min/max.  Like, if your file have min of 0 and max of 10, and you search for value 5, data skipping won't help, and you need to read file to find if you have data with value of 5.
- [Bloom filters](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/bloom-filters.html) - this is a closer to the "traditional indexing", as for each file there will be an additional data structure that will allow to check if your value **is definitely not in the file**, or **maybe is in the file**. Bloom filters allow to skip file reading more efficiently as it's checking for specific values.

I believe that in your case, bloom filters could be a best fit if you search for "primary key".